# visual studio 2013 issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2013

I have been using VS 2012 for development of asp.net MVC3 but now I have switched it to VS 2013 . What I find is interesting that as soon as I switched to 2013 all the helper methods(html.textboxFor()) stops working. Can anyone tell me the reason for this. Should I miss some reference while merging?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify what "not working" means?

Comment: It highlighted the txt with red color saying :system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper doesn't contains definition for textboxfor and no extension method 'textboxfor' accepting first argument of type system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper could be found